# What is $P(X=Y)$ and $P(X\le Y)$ when $X,Y$ are i.i.d integer-valued rvs?

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d integer-valued random variables and let $p_n =P\{X=n\}$. Find $P\{X=Y\}$ and $P\{X \leq Y\}$.

Can someone help me with this problem? My intuition is that the first probability should be 1/2 since there are only two situations, $X=Y$ and $X\neq Y$. The second probability is $3/4$ for similar reason.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting math correctly.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy already gave an answer below - but to challenge your intuition that $P(X=Y)=1/2$, try repeatedly rolling a pair of dice. Do you find that the scores on the two dice are equal half of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on $p_n$'s and your guesses are not correct. You can only say that $P(X=Y)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} p_n^{2}$ and $P(X\leq Y)= \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n \leq m}p_np_m$.

Comment: You can also say that $P(X\leq Y)=\frac{1+P(X=Y)}{2}$.

Comment: so there's no explicit formula for this but enumerating all the possible situations?